# Share Git Staging Area on local subnet(mostly wifi), now with images to explain

Tags: git

I know it sounds like a commit push, but what I would like to do here is have something done in code then stage but before pushing I would like to see what my local office partner(s) done, and he(they) see what I've done using the stage area (index), to work as a "caveat" for all local team members and to mentor them without the team leader leaving his seat, for example take a look at the following:

[image]

I want those connected to peek at each other **using their wifi** connection, but only Developers and the Team leader, anyone who is NOT A Developer shouldn't be able to see (so I can't use local shared directory)

[image]

Can  this be done or should I ask for it as an added feature?

P.S. Currently, we are exchanging files involved (Skype, duh!) but then again one can't simply do this unless those involved communicate verbally, mostly leave desk, and turn it into a real-time tutoring session, can't use diff (feature) as is, and worst of all if someone does some code that works and does a push and tests says yes, but days or weeks later turns out to be a simple-code(i.e. low conformity to design approach and how the architect wants it to be) and the need for it to be rewritten.

Comment: Work on branches?

Comment: the gist is for it to be integrated in the normal workflow but adds ease for "multiple eyes on code" in almost real-time

Comment: Yeah, so, pull requests?

Comment: Something like "Teletype for Atom", https://teletype.atom.io/ or "Visual Studio Live Share", https://code.visualstudio.com/visual-studio-live-share ?  In a Git way, you could exchange a patch. The patch could be a file or a commit. There are many methods to "exchange".

Comment: thanks for info @ElpieKay, but those are real-time and not "almost real-time", later today I'll post a drawing to further explain the question.

Comment: That's why I started with "I know it sounds like a commit push" @CodeCaster, wait for drawing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wandered from requirements to implementation details when you said "using the stage area", and it changes the answer considerably.

The stage area is not designed as a collaboration tool.  There is no straightforward way to use it as you describe.  You should not attempt to use it as you describe.  You can make a feature request, and I fully expect it will be disregarded, because git already has tools and patterns for collaboration and this isn't one of them.

If you want to share changes without pushing to origin, you can do any of:

a) Commit the changes locally, perhaps to a temporary branch, and then share that commit with your partner.  To share it, you can configure one another's repos as remotes, or you can pass bundle files containing the commit.

b) Create patch files from your index and/or working tree and share those.

c) Stash the changes, and share the stash.  This is a little trickier (beccuse it's not anticipated that you would share a stash), and doesn't buy you much relative to commit-and-share (in fact a stash is implemented using temporary commits anyway), but it can be done.

There's also probably not that much wrong with creating a temporary branch and pushing it to origin so your partner can fetch it, though depending on how your origin is hosted that might cause clutter to accumulate over time.

Comment: awesome knowledge you have, and I would like you to consider looking at the drawing which I'll post later today, maybe then it'll be clear what I'm asking for.

Comment: @YEH What is your reasoning for rejecting his solutions?  I suspect he is clear what is being asked, and you are unclear why these solutions fit what you are asking for.  I quote from above: **"You can make a feature request, and I fully expect it will be disregarded, because git already has tools and patterns for collaboration and this isn't one of them."**

Answer (score 0):

**[Edited, in response to comment from OP]**

- **Original Question:**

  > **Can this be done or should I ask for it as an added feature?**

  - **Part 1 Answer:** No, this cannot be done in Git
  - **Part 2 Answer:** It also should not be asked for as an added feature
  - **Reasoned Advice:** Use Git as intended with the mechanisms it already has to accomplish what you claim you are trying to achieve

You are free to reject the answer because you still want to do what you have apparently decided to do whether it is a good idea or not.  I do not see anything in your question or comments that explains why you cannot use additional branching and commits to have the exact same outcome that you claim you want, as explained below.

---

From a strictly Git perspective - no, you cannot share the index or any unstaged working directory changes directly in Git without some sort of commit (which could be a stash or normal commit).

From a Git perspective, though, this is what separate dev branches are really for.  Whatever branch is being worked on can have an infinite number of branches taken out by each individual developer and they can commit their progress on a regular basis in order to make those changes available to the team, create a restore point for additional work, and save the history.  For branches like that, you typically will want to merge with a single commit to the parent branch at the appropriate point and then delete all the "minute-by-minute" history, but some people prefer to save even the smallest level of history versus having a more clean history overall.

Going this route has a lot of benefits, specifically from a distributed perspective - people can work offline and sync up whenever needed, etc., in addition to all the SCM benefits in general - and it doesn't matter that a particular commit be "finished" or even compilable.  Pull requests can be made even if code isn't really ready to merge to provide a facility for review where the comments and action items can be tracked, depending how important that piece is to the team.  Of course, you'd need a convention to be clear about which ones are intended for merge and which are not.

---

#### Other options:

However, as the comments indicate, there are other options for more real-time sharing of current IDE status, if that's what you are really after.  But is it worth the fumbling with other tools and configurations, and setting everyone up on them, and maintaining them?  That's your call.  Perhaps one of the ones mentioned is already built-in to your environment:  [Teletype for Atom](https://teletype.atom.io/) or [Visual Studio Live Share](https://code.visualstudio.com/visual-studio-live-share).

Comment: first of all @LightCC good explanation, but, that's why I started with "I know it sounds like a commit push", and also I said in a comment almost real-time and not actual real-time, so I don't know maybe a doodle will help, will add to the question later today.

Comment: @YEH I'm just responding to your question with my answer to it.  Q: 
 *Can this be done or should I ask for it as an added feature?*.  A (part 1): *"this cannot be done"*.  A (part 2): *"it should not be asked for as an added feature"*.  What is your objection to using Git with the features that already exist (i.e. commits) to transfer working states?  Take a step back and look at the big picture - and decide not to attempt what you are trying to attempt - there is a better way, that is already possible.  That's my answer.